# Adding the date as index

Tags: r

Please suggest how can be indexed as a date to add to DF. When downloading quotes date has added index, it is required to do the same for df added by read.csv

this is example:

```
library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from=as.Date("2017-07-01",to=Sys.Date()))
[1] "GSPC"
> df<-read.csv("D:\\R\\tmp1\\SiM7.csv",header=F,skip=1,sep=";")
```

(as it should be)

```
> GSPC[1,]
       GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2017-07-03   2431.39   2439.17  2428.69    2429.01  1962290000       2429.01
>
```

(as it turns out)

```
> df[1,]
V1 V2       V3     V4    V5    V6    V7    V8     V9 V10
1 SiM7  5 20170522 100000 57236 57236 56767 56785 108295   0
>
```

add by index(df)<-df[,3] does not work, the date you want to add already existing and imported through read.csv Please help, thank you

Comment: What package does `index()` come from?  (From `index(df)<-df[,3]`).  I don't see it in [quantmod](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod).

Comment: Sorry, Index package:zoo(it's auto load with quantmod pckg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` works with zoo and xts objects as opposed to dataframes. See `?index` for more information. Also check out `class(GSPC)` and `class(df)` to see this difference.

If your goal is to transform your data.frame `df` into the same xts object as `GSPC` look at `?xts`.

First transform the date values in V3 into time-based objects. It appears as though your dates are numeric values. So `df_date_vec <- as.Date(as.character(df$V3), format = "%Y%m%d")` will create a date vector. Then you can create an xts object similar to `GSPC` by `sim_7 <- xts(df$V10, order.by = df_date_vec)`. Now `index(sim_7)` will return the dates.

This is assuming you want column V10. If you want multiple columns try `cbind`.

Comment: please tell me how to repeat this for time...
df[,4] - time 
I need date and time in index, example (date space time)

Comment: Check out [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html) for date and time formats.